# C# Convert INT to DATE

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I have a small Winforms test project, where I get name, lastname and age from textbox. In my database I have the columns name, lastname and birth. The birth column is datatype DATE. (SQL Server DB)

```
    TABLE CUSTOMER
column name - Datatype nvchar
column lastname - Datatype nvchar
column birth - Datatype DATE
```

I know how to get the data as insert statement into my DB.

My question is:

Is it possible that the age, which I get as INT, can be converted to DATE?

Example: age 38 from textbox -> this should be written as f.e. 27.03.1982 into DB.

Comment: How can you convert an `int`, which represents an age, into a `date`? For example. If I said I was 20 years old, that could mean my date of birth is any day between 28 March 1999 and 27 March 2020. You need the date of birth to accurately store the person's date of birth. If, for example, my Date of birth really were 28 March 1999 (which would have made me 12 when I joined SO!) then your data would be wrong from tomorrow.

Comment: @Larnu, I know that this is not realy good practice working, but I'm playing around a little bit and this question I couldn't answer by myself. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the age variable to the query and use `dateadd()`:

```
dateadd(year, @age, cast(getdate() as date))
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7ae9811d188db1aabb938b64fa4a6787)**:

```
select dateadd(year, -38, cast(getdate() as date)) birth;
```

```
| birth      |
| :--------- |
| 1982-03-27 |
```

Note that this is a rather inaccurate method to compute a date of birth; an age is a date interval, that should include months and days. You should probably ask users to provide their date of birth instead, from which you can derive the age.

Comment: thats exactly what I was looking for. I know that it is not good to work like this, but I'm playing around in C# and so I wanted to test something like this. Thank you.